# проблема с текстом в канвасе

Tags: javascript, canvas

Не получается сделать так, чтобы печатался текст на канвасе. Как довести до ума имеющийся код?
http://jsbin.com/fovivumiza/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что внутри функции `drawText()` вы использовали необъявленную переменную `ctx`, которая на самом деле было объявлена на второй строчке кода под именем `context`.

[Вот](http://jsbin.com/xecorixawi/6/edit?js,output) вполне работающий вариант.

---

Если ваш код не работает и вы не знаете почему, советую воспользоваться инспектором [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/).

Comment: точно!... вот она невнимательность. а как можно было бы сделать так, чтобы текст появлялся по мере печати?

Comment: @annussaa жутко тормозной, но все же [вариант](http://jsbin.com/viyalusuno/1/edit)